# Removing Duplicate documents using ElasticSearch's Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have these three documents in Elastic as shown below,

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-20T09:01:55.232Z",
    "outer": {
        "sequence": "44304",
        "reference": "1.2.3.4",
        "inner": {
            "first": {
                "reference": "moduleA",
                "identity": "mouduleA-alarm"
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-20T09:01:54.232Z",
    "outer": {
        "sequence": "44304",
        "reference": "1.2.3.4",
        "inner": {
            "first": {
                "reference": "moduleA",
                "identity": "mouduleA-alarm"
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-20T09:01:57.232Z",
    "outer": {
        "sequence": "44304",
        "reference": "1.2.3.4",
        "inner": {
            "second": {
                "reference": "moduleA",
                "identity": "mouduleA-alarm"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am running a query on these documents and then aggregating them. In aggregation the duplicate documents are removed on the basis of three fields.
The query goes like this :

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "dedup": {
            "terms": {  
                "script":"[doc['outer.reference'].value, doc['outer.inner.first.reference'].value, doc['outer.inner.first.identity'].value].join('_')",
                "lang": "groovy",
                "valueType": "string"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "dedup_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above query works fine, but the issue is the name of the container inside **inner** block are dynamic i.e they can be **first**, **second** and so on. But i need to access the the **reference** and the **identity** inside the **inner** block for aggregation.

I tried using regex inside the script but have not being successful.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "dedup": {
            "terms": {  
                "script":"[doc['outer.reference'].value, doc[/'outer.inner..+.reference'/].value, doc[/'outer.inner..+.identity'/].value].join('_')",
                "lang": "groovy",
                "valueType": "string"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "dedup_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above query throws value not found exception.

Note: The mapping in Elastic is dynamic templates with all fields as non_analyzed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your script you could find the first key and then use it dynamically

Something like this should do:

```
def array = [doc['outer.reference'].value]; 
def key = doc['outer.inner'].keySet().iterator.next();
array << doc['outer.inner'][key]['reference'].value;
array << doc['outer.inner'][key]['identity'].value;
return array.join('_')
```

Comment: Thanks Val, i can write this script in a file and pick the file from ElasticSearch's config. But is there a way to write this code in a single line, so that i can use an inline script rather than picking up from a script file.

Comment: That's why I've added the semicolons, just remove the new line characters. I've added them for readability's sake.

Comment: I am not able to take out the keySet for the **inner** block. Is this because of a flat list ? I am able to access **doc['outer.inner.first.reference']** but not getting the keySet for any container.

Comment: Can you tell which version of ES you have?

Comment: Using an old one. Its 1.7

Comment: Ok, I'll try again on that version

Comment: did you try with 1.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
def array = [_source.outer.reference]; 
def key = _source.outer.inner.keySet().iterator.next();
array << _source.outer.inner[key]['reference'];
array << _source.outer.inner[key]['identity'];
return array.join('_')
```

Using **doc** was not returning the JSON for a container value, but using **_source** did.

Thanks Val for the help.